# Python: Loop over multiple items

Tags: python, pandas, database, loops, timestamp

Let's start with a simple DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[100,100,105,110,100,106,120,110,105,70,90, 100]})
df:
    a
0   100
1   100
2   105
3   110
4   100
5   106
6   120
7   110
8   105
9   70
10  90
11  100
```

Now, I want to calculate the returns on a 7-day rolling basis. So I apply the following:

```
df['delta_rol_a_last_first'] = np.nan
for i in range(7,len(df)):
    df['delta_rol_a_last_first'].iloc[i] = (df['a'].iloc[i] - df['a'].iloc[i-7])/df['a'].iloc[i-6]
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df:
    a    delta_rol_a_last_first
7   110   0.100000
8   105   0.047619
9   70   -0.318182
10  90   -0.200000
11  100   0.000000
```

Now I just want the negative returns, apply quantiles to them and I want to add identities to the rows as follows:

```
df_quant = df['delta_rol_a_last_first'][df['delta_rol_a_last_first'] <0].quantile([0.01,0.03,0.05,0.1])
df_quant.index.names = ['quantile']
df_quant=df_quant.to_frame()
df_quant['Type'] = 'pct'
df_quant['timeframe'] = 'weekly'
df_quant:
            delta_rol_a_last_first   Type   timeframe
quantile            
    0.01                 -0.317000   pct    weekly
    0.03                 -0.314636   pct    weekly
    0.05                 -0.312273   pct    weekly
    0.10                 -0.306364   pct    weekly
```

So that works perfectly.

Now imagine I want to do the same but more dynamically. So consider a DataFrame with multiple columns as follows:

```
data = [[99330,12,122],[1123,1230,1287],[123,101,812739],[1143,1230123,252],[234,342,4546],[2445,3453,3457],[7897,8657,5675],[46,5675,453],[76,484,3735],[363,93,4568],[385,568,367],[458,846,4847],[574,45747,658468],[57457,46534,4675]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
                       '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08',
                       '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12',
                       '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14'], 
          columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C'])
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df1: 
            col_A   col_B   col_C
2022-01-01  99330   12      122
2022-01-02  1123    1230    1287
2022-01-03  123     101     812739
2022-01-04  1143    1230123 252
2022-01-05  234     342     4546
2022-01-06  2445    3453    3457
2022-01-07  7897    8657    5675
2022-01-08  46      5675    453
2022-01-09  76      484     3735
2022-01-10  363     93      4568
2022-01-11  385     568     367
2022-01-12  458     846     4847
2022-01-13  574     45747   658468
2022-01-14  57457   46534   4675
```

I will create a dictionary for the periods over which I want to calculate my rolling returns:

```
periodicity_dict = {'1D':'daily', '1W':'weekly'}
```

Now I want to create the same DataFrame as `df_quant` above. So my DataFrame should look something like this:

```
                     col_A_rolling  col_B_rolling   col_C_rolling    Type   timeframe  
quantile    
    0.01                 -0.317000         -0.234         -0.0443     pct      weekly
    0.03                 -0.314636         -0.022            ...      pct      weekly
    0.05                 ...                 ...             ...      ...             
    0.10                 ...                 ...
    0.01                 ...                 ...
    0.03                 ...                 ...
    0.05                 ...                 ...
    0.10                 -0.306364          -.530023                  pct       daily
```

(NOTE: the numbers in this DataFrame are hypothetical)

EDIT:

My attempt is this:

```
periodicity_dict = {'1D':'daily', '1W':'weekly'}
df_columns = df1.columns
for key in periodicity_dict:
    for col in df_columns:
        df1[col+'_rolling']= np.nan
        for i in pd.date_range(start=df1[col].first_valid_index(), end=df1[col].last_valid_index(), freq=key):
            df1[col+'_rolling'].iloc[i] = (df1[col].iloc[i] - df1[col].iloc[i-key])/df1[col].iloc[i-key]
```

What is the best way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: pandas has function for rolling [DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: None of these work. What I want is the return and I'm not sure how to do that with rolling

Comment: `df["delta_rol_a_last_first'] = df.rolling(8).apply(lambda data:(data.iloc[-1] - data.iloc[0])/data.iloc[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test all code but first part can be replaced by `DataFrame.roling`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[100,100,105,110,100,106,120,110,105,70,90, 100]})

# ---

def convert(data):
    return (data.iloc[-1] - data.iloc[0])/data.iloc[1]

df[['delta_rol_a_last_first']] =  df.rolling(8).apply(convert)

# ---

print(df)
```

or using `lambda`

```
df[['delta_rol_a_last_first']] =  df.rolling(8).apply(lambda data: ((data.iloc[-1] - data.iloc[0])/data.iloc[1]))
```

---

The same for many columns:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [99330,12,122], [1123,1230,1287], [123,101,812739], [1143,1230123,252], 
    [234,342,4546], [2445,3453,3457], [7897,8657,5675], [46,5675,453],
    [76,484,3735],  [363,93,4568],    [385,568,367],    [458,846,4847],
    [574,45747,658468], [57457,46534,4675]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
        data,
        index=['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
               '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08',
               '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12',
               '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14'], 
        columns=['col_A', 'col_B', 'col_C']
)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# ---

def convert(data):
    return (data.iloc[-1] - data.iloc[0])/data.iloc[1]

#df[['col_A_weekly', 'col_B_weekly', 'col_C_weekly']] =  df.rolling(8).apply(convert)

new_columns = [name+'_weekly' for name in df.columns]
df[new_columns] =  df.rolling(8).apply(convert)

# ---

print(df)
```

Result:

```
            col_A    col_B   col_C  col_A_weekly  col_B_weekly  col_C_weekly
2022-01-01  99330       12     122           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-02   1123     1230    1287           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-03    123      101  812739           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-04   1143  1230123     252           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-05    234      342    4546           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-06   2445     3453    3457           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-07   7897     8657    5675           NaN           NaN           NaN
2022-01-08     46     5675     453    -88.409617      4.604065      0.257187
2022-01-09     76      484    3735     -8.512195     -7.386139      0.003012
2022-01-10    363       93    4568      0.209974     -0.000007  -3207.027778
2022-01-11    385      568     367     -3.239316  -3595.190058      0.025297
2022-01-12    458      846    4847      0.091616      0.145960      0.087070
2022-01-13    574    45747  658468     -0.236925      4.885526    115.420441
2022-01-14  57457    46534    4675   1077.391304      6.674361     -2.207506
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using two ranges `daily` and `weekly`

```
old_columns = df.columns

new_columns = [name+'_weekly' for name in old_columns]
df[new_columns] =  df[old_columns].rolling(8).apply(convert)

new_columns = [name+'_daily' for name in old_columns]
df[new_columns] =  df[old_columns].rolling(2).apply(convert)
```

or using loop:

```
old_columns = df.columns  

for days, suffix in ((1, 'daily'), (7, 'weekly')):
    new_columns = [name+'_'+suffix for name in old_columns]
    df[new_columns] = df[old_columns].rolling(days+1).apply(convert)
```

or

```
for days, suffix in ((1, 'daily'), (7, 'weekly')):
    for name in old_columns:
        new_name = name + '_' + suffix
        df[new_name] = df[name].rolling(days+1).apply(convert)
```

Result:

```
            col_A    col_B   col_C  col_A_weekly  col_B_weekly  col_C_weekly  col_A_daily  col_B_daily  col_C_daily
2022-01-01  99330       12     122           NaN           NaN           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
2022-01-02   1123     1230    1287           NaN           NaN           NaN   -87.450579     0.990244     0.905206
2022-01-03    123      101  812739           NaN           NaN           NaN    -8.130081   -11.178218     0.998416
2022-01-04   1143  1230123     252           NaN           NaN           NaN     0.892388     0.999918 -3224.154762
2022-01-05    234      342    4546           NaN           NaN           NaN    -3.884615 -3595.850877     0.944567
2022-01-06   2445     3453    3457           NaN           NaN           NaN     0.904294     0.900956    -0.315013
2022-01-07   7897     8657    5675           NaN           NaN           NaN     0.690389     0.601132     0.390837
2022-01-08     46     5675     453    -88.409617      4.604065      0.257187  -170.673913    -0.525463   -11.527594
2022-01-09     76      484    3735     -8.512195     -7.386139      0.003012     0.394737   -10.725207     0.878715
2022-01-10    363       93    4568      0.209974     -0.000007  -3207.027778     0.790634    -4.204301     0.182356
2022-01-11    385      568     367     -3.239316  -3595.190058      0.025297     0.057143     0.836268   -11.446866
2022-01-12    458      846    4847      0.091616      0.145960      0.087070     0.159389     0.328605     0.924283
2022-01-13    574    45747  658468     -0.236925      4.885526    115.420441     0.202091     0.981507     0.992639
2022-01-14  57457    46534    4675   1077.391304      6.674361     -2.207506     0.990010     0.016912  -139.848770
```

---

**EDIT:**

Quantile:

```
finall_df = pd.DataFrame()

for days, suffix in ((1, 'daily'), (7, 'weekly')):
    df_quant = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for name in old_columns:
        new_name = name + '_' + suffix
        df_quant[name] = df[new_name][df[new_name]<0].quantile([0.01,0.03,0.05,0.1])
        
    df_quant.index.names = ['quantile']
    df_quant['Type'] = 'pct'
    df_quant['timeframe'] = suffix
    print(df_quant.to_string())
    
    #finall_df = finall_df.append(df_quant)
    finall_df = pd.concat([finall_df,df_quant])
    
print(finall_df)
```

Result:

```
               col_A        col_B        col_C Type timeframe
quantile                                                     
0.01     -168.177213 -3452.463971 -3100.782522  pct     daily
0.03     -163.183813 -3165.690158 -2854.038043  pct     daily
0.05     -158.190413 -2878.916345 -2607.293564  pct     daily
0.10     -145.706913 -2161.981813 -1990.432365  pct     daily
0.01      -86.012694 -3523.433980 -3174.979575  pct    weekly
0.03      -81.218849 -3379.921823 -3110.883170  pct    weekly
0.05      -76.425004 -3236.409666 -3046.786764  pct    weekly
0.10      -64.440391 -2877.629275 -2886.545751  pct    weekly
```